# Which MobX pattern to use to detect a change and change other observables?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I read the description of [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html) and [reaction](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html) multiple times, but it is still not clear to me which pattern to use when I detect a change in one observable and I want to update other observables.

**Example**

I have an address object shown below. Whenever the country changes, I want to reset/reinitialize all the other fields. One way to do this is to have an `@action setCountry() {...}` inside the `Address` class which takes care of setting the other observables. However, I don't have that luxury because my UI uses generic techniques to update store attributes, namely `_.set(entity, attr, value)`. So I would like to use something like `autorun` to detect the change and update the rest of the observables. What's the right way to do this?

```
class Address {
    @observable name;
    @observable line1;
    @observable line2;
    @observable city;
    @observable state;
    @observable zip;
    @observable country;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Exactly how would you like to update your other observables? To me this sounds like a great use case for [**computed**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/computed-decorator.html), so that your derived values are updated automatically.

Comment: Well, the other values are not derived, so computed is not appropriate in this case. One use case is this: depending on the chosen country I want to default the other observables to the head office in that country - which may be desirable 90% of the time. However, the user is then free to change the address to anything else. This is where I would like to watch changes to country and react appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [**observe**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html#observe) would work well for your use case.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vevobivedu/1/edit?js,console)**)

```
class Address {
  @observable name = '';
  @observable line1 = '';
  @observable line2 = '';
  @observable city = '';
  @observable state = '';
  @observable zip = '';
  @observable country = '';
}

const address = new Address();

observe(address, change => {
  if (change.name === 'country' && change.newValue === 'Sweden') {
    address.city = 'Stockholm';
  }
});

autorun(() => {
  console.log(toJS(address));
});

setTimeout(() => {
  address.country = 'Sweden';
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tholle. This is extremely useful. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to put the `observe()` inside the `Address` class and also capture it's disposer? I would really like `Address` instances to encapsulate this logic.

Comment: @Naresh No problem! You could do [**something like this**](http://jsbin.com/podikusolu/1/edit?js,console) and call the custom `destroy` method when you want to the dispose the listener.

Comment: That's perfect, @Tholle! Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Naresh Great! Glad I could help.